# Assign class variable to function and call

Tags: php, class

Looking for the way to assign a function to a class variable and then call it.

I know you can assign the class var to another variable and then call it, but I am looking for a way to call without creating temporary variables and cluttering up my code.

Are temporary variables or using `call_user_func()` my only options?

```php
class MyClass {
    public $callMe;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->callMe = function(...$args) {
            print_r(['HIT', $args]);
        };

        // $this->callMe('asd', 'sda');
        // Error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method test::callMe()

        // This works, but I would prefer not to create temporary variables for this
        $tmp = $this->callMe;
        $tmp('sd','adsf','fdas');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the following:

```
($this->callMe)('sd','adsf','fdas');
call_user_func($this-callMe, 'sd','adsf','fdas');
```